# Best Way to Increase Rendering Performance in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

Hello everyone I’ve been developing a game recently and I am trying to optimize it on low end machines. It is 2D tile based game(in other words I draw many quads on screen). I first used immediate mode with around 40-50fps depending on the amount of objects on screen, I then used display lists with little to no increase in fps, and then VBOs again with little no increase in fps, I have now switched back to display lists. I believe my performance cap to be when I render the quads, I do many transformation such as translate, scale, and rotate. My question being how can I go about reducing the number of transformations I need to make each draw call, in order to increase fps.

Creating the list.

```
    quad = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(quad, GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(0,0);

            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(1,0);

            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(1,1);

            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex2f(0,1);
        glEnd();
    glEndList();
```

Then for every quad my draw method looks like this.

```
    tex.bind();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(InputControl.zoomPosX, InputControl.zoomPosY, 0);
    glScaled(zoom,zoom, 0); 
    glTranslatef(-InputControl.zoomPosX, -InputControl.zoomPosY, 0);

    glTranslatef(x+ width / 2, y + height / 2, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0 ,0 , 1);
    glTranslatef(- width / 2, - height / 2, 0);

    glColor4f(r,g,b, alpha);
    glScaled(width,height,0);
    glCallList(quad);

    glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- forget the display list. It'd deprecated and some drivers implement it via VBO.
  Better to make things modern and explicit.
- use a sampler, set the min/mag filter and the wrap on that and bind it just once if all those settings are the same for all the textures.
- same for the blending, if it's always the same, take it out from the quad loop.
- try to upload all vertex data, including the color, into VBO.
- if the textures have all the same dimension, use a texture array. Same for the matrices, calculate all the matrices once and upload them once at begin. Then, use instance rendering and use the index to access the i-th matrix and texture inside the shader